# navigation menu last item appearing and dissapearing on resizing

Tags: html, css, menu

I have the below nav menu and whenever i resize using the ctrl+right click the last item FAQ appears and dissapears..not to mention it also breaks my entire site background represented by 2 images.
whats wrong and how to make it stay the same on resizing? cheers!

html:

```
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
           <li class='active '><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>about us</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>our errand ladies</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>schedule an errand</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>contact us</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>faq</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.nav {
            width: 100%;
            height: 63px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .nav ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
            width: auto;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            height: 63px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 21px;
            background: transparent url('images/nav-bg-repeat.png') repeat-x top left;
            font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }
        .nav li {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }
        .nav li a {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            text-decoration: none; 
            padding:0 30px;
            height: 63px;
            line-height: 63px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background: transparent url('images/divider.png') no-repeat top right;
            }
        .nav li a:hover {
            background: transparent url('images/nav-hover.png') repeat-x top right; 
            }

        .nav li a span {
            color: #000;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `overflow: hidden;` set on your `.nav` element and no width defined.

By default, the `.nav` is set to 100% width, as it's a block element.  It will automatically span the width of the parent it's currently sitting in.

When you resize the window down to a size that cannot fit the links, they fall outside of the .nav and are hidden from view.

You can set a fixed width to your `.nav` (or parent container) to prevent it from collapsing in width.

```
.nav {
  width: 960px;
}
```

Or if you still want it to collapse, but still show the nav links, you can remove  `overflow: hidden;` and the elements will appear (however, they will not be inline with each other.

Comment: Axel, thanks for making me understand this better.  however, set the menu to a fixed width and the menu last item still collapses if i zoom out...

Comment: blackbee, used a fixed width with overflow to none and the last menu item still goes under the main menu when i zoom out...

Comment: maybe i should put the whole page on jsfiddle for you guys to see.. ?

Comment: What results are you looking for?  Nothing it out of the ordinary here.  You're working with variable widths, and static content.  If the widths aren't wide enough to hold the content, it will either collapse or disappear, depending on how you setup the parent containers.  I suggest you use some browser debugging tools to adjust font sizes, margins and widths to determine the most optimal CSS attributes required for your page content.

Answer (score 0):

for the second problem set the

```
body{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

and it disappears as overflow is hidden; set it to none

```
.nav{
width:1000px;
overflow:none;
..
}
```

the way i see is you are trying to put the list elements inline so you can try this code and modify the looks:

```
<ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
<li><a href="#">There</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


#navlist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```